# What is the "Sexateria"?

Tags: futurama, real-location

In *Futurama* episode two "This Series Has Landed", Bender says this about Fry:

> You're the kind of guy who visits Jerusalem and doesn't want to see the "Sexateria."

What is this referring to?

Comment: A cafeteria of sex?

Comment: -teria suffix denote self-service establishments.

So Sexateria would be Handjob self-service establement.

Comment: The joke here is that Jersualem, a city considered holy in multiple religions, has become the site of some sort of sexual services. I think it's supposed to be left to our imaginations exactly what sort of lewdness is performed there.

Comment: Am I the only person who saw this title and thought it would be something about "six" in Latin?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yes. Yes you are.

Comment: @Randal'Thor no, you're not.

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, *I'm* the only one that saw the title and thought that. You're an imposter.

Comment: In a similar matter, Zapp Brannigan is suffering from severe "sexlexia"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Sexateria is not a real thing. By analogy with "cafeteria," the implication is that the Sexateria is a place where sex is purchased and enjoyed—presumably in the open, casual manner in which food is enjoyed at a cafeteria. (The joke is that this brothel has edged out e.g. the Wailing Wall as the must-see tourist destination of the 31st century's Holy Land.)

The suffix "-eria" is Italian, equivalent to "-ery" in English (and "-ería" in Spanish). I think the only English "-eria" words are "cafeteria," "pizzeria," and "washeteria," which is a new one on me. (Maybe we can count "taquería" too.) So it makes sense that the etymology of "Sexateria" is opaque to viewers who haven't been thinking about cafeterias lately.